# Using SQL hint to Force Index using querydsl

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

We are using `querydsl` with JPA in our application. Below is how my repository implementation:

```
public interface TestRepository  extends JpaRepository<Test, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Test> {   }
```

I am calling default findAll method using predicate builder and pageable object:

```
testRepository.findAll(booleanBuilder.getValue(), pageable);
```

In order to address performance issues, we need to force index on the specific tables. Right now derivative query looks as below:

`SELECT tab1_.id AS id_20_, tab1_.user_type AS user_type2_20_ FROM table1 tab1_`

And we want our query to look as this:

`SELECT /*+ INDEX(tab1_ MGS_KG1) */ tab1_.id AS id_20_, tab1_.user_type AS user_type2_20_ FROM table1 tab1_`

How can I achieve the same? (we are using querydsl-jpa 3.6.7)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [interceptors](http://learningviacode.blogspot.com.by/2012/06/intercepting-events-in-hibernate.html)

```
public String onPrepareStatement(String sql);
```

Just call `super` and modify the result SQL string inserting your index string after `SELECT` if `FROM` contains necessary table